# How to validate XML file against DTD and XML schema in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating XML file from SQL SERVER database. This saves XML file into computer:

```
List<Product> prList = db.Product.ToList();
        if (prList.Count > 0)
        {
            var xEle = new XElement("Products",
                from product in prList
                select new XElement("Product",
                    new XElement("ProductId", product.Id),
                    new XElement("Name", product.Name),
                    new XElement("Desctiption", product.Description),
                    new XElement("Price", product.Price),
                    new XElement("PictureURL", product.PictureURL),
                    new XElement("Category", product.Category.CategoryName)
                    ));
            HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Write(xEle);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Products.xml");
            context.Response.End();

            return View();
        }
        return View();
```

I have DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT Products ((Product+))>
<!ELEMENT ProductId (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Product ((ProductId, Name, Desctiption, Price, PictureURL, Category))>
<!ELEMENT Price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PictureURL (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Desctiption (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Category (#PCDATA)>
```

and XML schema:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Products">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Product" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ProductId">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ProductId"/>
                <xs:element ref="Name"/>
                <xs:element ref="Desctiption"/>
                <xs:element ref="Price"/>
                <xs:element ref="PictureURL"/>
                <xs:element ref="Category"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Price">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                <xs:enumeration value="12400.0"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="15.0"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="29.0"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="388.0"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="69.0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="PictureURL" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Desctiption" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Category">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="Beauty"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Electronics"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Office"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Sports"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Watches"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My problem is I do not know how to validate my creating XML against DTD and XML schema in runtime. Please, can you give your suggestions how to implement this? What is the easiest way?

I have database which includes Products table. Products table's attributes: Id, Name, Description, Price, PictureURL, Category(FK to Category table's Id). I am taking all products in the form of list. Then saving into XML file. My CW task requires me to validate against DTD and XML schema.

Answer (score 0):

I know how you can validate with the xsd:

```
var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(null, schema); // schema can be a string or a path.
bool hasErrors = false;
document.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
    hasErrors = true;
});
```

And for the DTD, this should get you started:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"file.xml", settings))
{
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read()) { }
    }
    catch (XmlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```